# Unable to check if the persisted state has been loaded or not on index/main file using redux-persist in react-native app

Tags: android, react-native, redux, redux-persist

I am using redux and redux-persist to save and persist the state. 
In my app, I need to decide the default screen based on saved state in redux.

**For example** - If the user has already been logged-in then he should not see the login screen again when he opens the app. I need to directly jump him to next screen.

But even if I am rendering my component in **PersistGate**, I am getting the initial state defined in my **User** reducer and user is always being redirected to login screen. On login screen,I am getting the persisted state. The only issue is that I don't find any way to get persisted state in index.js file.

This is my **index.js** file, in which I have added an alert statement where I am getting the initial state rather than persisted state  -

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { StyleProvider } from "native-base";
import reduxStore from "./setup/Store";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import Navigator from "./setup/Routes";
import SplashScreen from "react-native-splash-screen";
import Walkthrough from "./screens/Walkthrough/Walkthrough";

export default class Main extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    SplashScreen.hide();
  }

  render() {
    const Login = Navigator("CustomerLogin");
    const Profile = Navigator("Profile");
    const Home = Navigator("CustomerHome");
    return (
      <Provider store={reduxStore.store}>
        <PersistGate persistor={reduxStore.persistor}>
          {alert(JSON.stringify(reduxStore.store.getState().User))}
          {reduxStore.store.getState().User.is_logged_in &&
          !reduxStore.store.getState().User.is_registered ? (
            <Profile />
          ) : reduxStore.store.getState().User.is_registered ? (
            <Home />
          ) : reduxStore.store.getState().User.walkthrough_visible ? (
            <Walkthrough navigation={Login} />
          ) : (
            <Login />
          )}
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

and this is my Store.js file -

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage"; // defaults to localStorage for web and AsyncStorage for react-native
import Reducers from "./Reducer";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import rootSaga from "./Sagas";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const middleWare = [sagaMiddleware];

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, Reducers);

// Add the autoRehydrate middleware to your redux store
const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  compose(applyMiddleware(...middleWare))
);

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

let persistor = persistStore(store);

// Enable persistence
export default { store, persistor };
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

state is loaded async, and you need wait until finished. 
For similar situations see PersistGate `loading` or `onBeforeLift` props

https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/docs/PersistGate.md

```
<PersistGate
  loading={<CircularIndicator message={"loading"} />}
  onBeforeLift={onBeforeLift}
  persistor={persistor}
>
<Router />
</PersistGate>
```

**UPDATE2:**

better is used state, what is passed down from `PersistGate`.
you can create connected branching component:

```
        const Branch=({User})=><View>{
          !User.is_registered ? (
          <Profile />
          ) : User.is_registered ? (
          <Home />
          ) : User.walkthrough_visible ? (
          <Walkthrough navigation={Login} />
          ) : (
          <Login />
        )}</View>

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return {
        User: state.User/// get user
      }
    }

    const BranchWithUser = connect(
      mapStateToProps,
    )(Branch)



export default class Main extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    SplashScreen.hide();
  }

  render() {
    const Login = Navigator("CustomerLogin");
    const Profile = Navigator("Profile");
    const Home = Navigator("CustomerHome");
    return (
      <Provider store={reduxStore.store}>
        <PersistGate
          loading={<CircularIndicator message={"loading"} />}
          onBeforeLift={onBeforeLift}
          persistor={persistor}
        >
        <BranchWithUser />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't PersistGate wait until the state has been retrieved? I had the impression that it delays the rendering of your app's UI until your persisted state has been retrieved. It is mentioned the doc - https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist